# Angular TypeScript: Create substitute $this in class

Tags: javascript, angular, class

How do you guys implement a substitue variable for **this** inside a class in TypeScript?

This technique is useful to save and recall your (parent/child) class or function when entering another code segment whereas **this** is replaced by the current context.

As in JS:

```
class Foo {
  var $this = this;
}
```

Meanwhile in TS, the keyword **var** is not allowed inside a class.

Comment: It would be `private $this = this;` but I have never had to do that in my Typescript code. For callbacks, use arrow functions. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1009922) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Connor, I got the answer with arrow functions, though private $this = this could not be accessed